# How to calculate the average of a sequence with more weight toward more frequent values?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, average, time-series

I have a long sequence containing $n$ values like below:

```
[1,2,1,3,1,1,3,3,1,200,1,1,40,1,....,1]
```

in which, the majority of the values are smaller than $k$ (unknown), and a few numbers are bigger than $3*k$. I want to filter out those few values in the sequence.

I thought if somehow I can find the average of those frequent values (which are below $k$) then I can use it as a threshold. But I do not know $k$.

Any opinion?

Comment: What is meant by "the majority"? If the numbers are randomly generated then it is unlikely this filtration can be performed as it is not impossible for every number to be greater than $3k$.

Comment: Consider the [trimmed mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) or the [Winsorized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing).